# How to add missing library after upgrading to firebase-bom:27.0.0?

Tags: android, firebase, maven-bom

I have following firebase libraries:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
```

after I upgrade them to 27.0.0

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
```

This library disapper:

```
com.google.androind.gsm:play-services-base:17.0.0@aar
```

Which brakes following import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability
```

Any idea how to fix this properly?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding manually this version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0'
```

I hope it is correct version, because '**com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement**' was also **17.3.0** which has dependecy from '**com.google.firebase:firebase-bom**'.

But this solution is not nice, because I have to check if I use correct version after each BOM update, which makes BOM idea (use all compatible libraries by itself) pretty useless.

It is also strange, that last available version is **com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0**.